# Make a web site that logs user out at a particular duration

Tags: php

What's the best way to make a web site that won't log out the user till I say so -- whatever the session duration default may be?

My current code uses a cookie that expires after a set duration:

```
setcookie('user_id', sha1($username),time()+SOME_INTERVAL); //sha1 encrypts the username
```

But I am uncertain about the security of this.

I would be happier using sessions, regenerated as need be.  But I'm not sure how to be sure the session won't stop earlier.

This is a package I will be sharing, so I want to do whatever I do in my code, rather than in the web site's configuration.

Comment: Looks like I've been offensive, but I don't know what I said!

Comment: Putting plain text in the cookie is a bad idea, since the user can create the cookie without ever logging in. You need to use some form of encryption to prevent spoofing.

Comment: Got it covered; thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a web page that wants to keep the user logged in, I set the cookie to:

```
setcookie("login_token", $username . '|' . sha1($secret . $username . $password), time() + SOME_INTERVAL);
```

The secret prevents users from creating the cookie themselves; it also allows us to invalidate all logins by changing the secret. And concatenating the password means that if they change their password their logins will be invalidated (since they might have changed it because someone broke into their account, so they should be blocked).

When they come back, it extracts the username from before `|`, looks up their password, and checks whether the SHA1 matches the cookie.

Comment: So would you say that using cookies (plus encryption) is just as secure as using sessions?  I do like the control this gives me over duration, and other details.  But my impression was that sessions are better because they're stored on the server.

Comment: Sessions don't last long, they use session cookies rather than permanent cookies.

Comment: And they also get garbage collected on the server, although you can configure that.

Comment: The application we use this for is not critical like financial data. I'm not sure if I would use something like this if extreme security is needed. But you probably shouldn't let people stay logged in forever in such an application.

Comment: I'm using hash with `hash` instead of `sha1`, but this is what I did.  Thanks!

Comment: It's the same idea.

Comment: `sha1` is old and no longer considered secure.